# Php - Delete files older than 7 days for multiple folders

Tags: php, automation, path, delete-file

i would like to create a PHP script that delete files from multiple folders/paths.
I managed something but I would like to adapt this code for more specific folders.

This is the code:

```
<?php
function deleteOlderFiles($path,$days) {
  if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      $filelastmodified = filemtime($path . $file);
      if((time() - $filelastmodified) > $days*24*3600)
      {
        if(is_file($path . $file)) {
          unlink($path . $file);
        }
      }
    }
    closedir($handle);
  }
}

$path = 'C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Temp';
$days = 7;
deleteOlderFiles($path,$days);
?>
```

I would like to make something like to add more paths and this function to run for every path.
I tried to add multiple path locations but it didn't work because it always takes the last $ path variable.
For exemple:

```
$path = 'C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Temp';
$path = 'C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Temp/bla';
$path = 'C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Temp/blabla';
$path = 'C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Temp/blalbalba';
$days = 7;
deleteOlderFiles($path,$days);
```

Thank you for you help!

Comment: _“because it always takes the last $ path variable”_ - of course it does, because you are overwriting the same variable multiple times there. If _that_ already “surprised” you, then you should perhaps start with a beginner tutorial that explains some basics first?

Comment: Off you go then, its not necesssary to tell us what you are doing today, but I guess its nice of you to let us know your plans

Comment: You can put your paths into an _array_, and then loop over that. Either loop outside the function, and inside the loop call it for one path each time - or pass the array to the function, and then loop over it inside the function.

Comment: @CBroe I understand and thank you for your help. Could you please if it is not difficult to show me practically how I could do this?

Comment: Don't use salutations: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: DON'T use the `script` tag. It offers no information at all. All SO questions are about scripts one way or another. It's no better than adding `program` or `code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution, call the function after setting the parameter not after setting all the possible parameters into a scalar variable.

```
$days = 7;

$path = 'C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Temp';
deleteOlderFiles($path,$days);

$path = 'C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Temp/bla';
deleteOlderFiles($path,$days);

$path = 'C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Temp/blabla';
deleteOlderFiles($path,$days);

$path = 'C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Temp/blalbalba';
deleteOlderFiles($path,$days);
```

Alternatively, place the directories in an array and then call the funtion from within a foreach loop.

```
$paths = [];
$paths[] = 'C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Temp';
$paths[] = 'C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Temp/bla';
$paths[] = 'C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Temp/blabla';
$paths[] = 'C:/Users/Legion/AppData/Local/Temp/blalbalba';

$days = 7;

foreach ( $paths as $path){
    deleteOlderFiles($path,$days);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @RiggsFolly. It's working like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need a recursive function, i.e. a function that calls itself. In this case it calls itself when it finds a subdirectory to scan/traverse.

```
function delete_files($current_path, $days) {
    $files_in_current_path = scandir($current_path);
    foreach($files_in_current_path as $file) {
        if (!in_array($release_file, [".", ".."])) {
            if (is_dir($current_path . "/" . $file)) {
                // Scan found subdirectory
                delete_files($current_path . "/" . $file, $days);
            } else {
                // Here you add your code for checking date and deletion of the $file
               $filelastmodified = filemtime($current_path . "/" . $file);
               if((time() - $filelastmodified) > $days*24*3600) {
                  if(is_file($current_path . "/" . $file)) {
                      unlink($current_path . "/". $file);
                  }
               }
            } 
        }
    }
}
delete_files("your/startpath/here", 7);
```

This code starts in your specified start path. It scans all files in that directory. If a sub directory is found, there will be a new call to `delete_files`, but with that sub directory as a start.

Comment: For you for your help @gowrie, my goal is not to search in every subfolder. I have some specific folders in my computer that i would like to run the function. That's why i would like to make an array and add multiple paths in it and after that to run the function for every patch each time. theoretically I know what to do but practically I don't know how to do it.